# android - Ошибка при создании адаптера из ArrayList

Tags: java, android, ооп, listview, android-asynctask

Я подключаюсь к серверу, получаю `Json` массив. Затем достаю из него все `Json` объекты и помещаю в `ArrayList` все значения ключа "id". Из этого `ArrayList` я создаю адаптер чтобы забить данными ListView. Все это дело происходит в `AsyncTask` и я не могу найти причину вот такой ошибки:

> There is no appicable constructor to
>   (com.test.getArray.RegisterAccessActivity.StartAcsess,int,java.util.ArrayList)

***Полный код класса...***

```
public class RegisterAccessActivity extends Activity {
    String server_name = "http://dev.pareto-marketing.ru/access/";
    Button test;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.acsess);
       lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
       test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.test);
       test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
             StartAcsess acsess_start = new StartAcsess();
             acsess_start.execute();        
          }
       });      
    }

    private class StartAcsess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
       JSONArray JsonArray;
       JSONObject jsonobject;
       HttpURLConnection conn;
       String json_bum, bfr_st;
       ArrayList<String> Arraylist;
       ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

       protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

       try {
          String post_url = server_name + "index.php?load";
          URL url = new URL(post_url);
          conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
          conn.connect(); //коннект
          InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); //канал
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

          while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) 
          {
             sb.append(bfr_st);
          }

          json_bum = sb.toString(); 
          JsonArray = new JSONArray(json_bum);
          is.close();
          br.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {

       } finally {
          conn.disconnect();
       }
       return json_bum;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String json_bum) {
       try{
          for (int u=0; u<JsonArray.length(); u++){ 
             jsonobject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(u);
             Arraylist.add(jsonobject.getString("id")); //создаём массив из всех значений

          }

          listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, Arraylist); 
           lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

       } catch (Exception e) {


       } finally{

       }
    }
  }
}
```

Насчёт сервера и корректности массива - данные без проблем выводились в TextView. Проблема при создании адаптера...

**РЕШЕНИЕ =)**

**Новый onPostExecute()**

```
protected void onPostExecute(String json_bum) {
  try{
     arraylist=new ArrayList(); //инициализация 
     for (int u=0; u<JsonArray.length(); u++) { 
         jsonobject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(u);
         arraylist.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
     }

     listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegisterAccessActivity.this, R.layout.simplerow, arraylist);
     lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

   } catch (Exception e) {

   } finally {

   }
}
```

Comment: Инициализируйте ваш ```Arraylist```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым аргументом конструктор класса `ArrayAdapter` принимает контекст, вы же ему передаёте `this`, коий, будучи написан внутри класса `StartAcsess` содержит ссылку на него, а не на требуемый `Context`.

**Решение:**

Поменяйте `this` на `RegisterAccessActivity.this` или, что лучше, передавайте контекст через конструктор задачи.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, у вас список не инициализирован, т.е. null. Почему так - только вам известно должно быть) И кстати, имена переменных должны быть с маленькой буквы - переименуйте  ваш ArrayList

Comment: огромное спасибо)) после инициализации и переименования переменной, ListView наконец-то готов!